# unable to burn iso

Tags: iso, brasero

hello trying to burn dban onto a cd r 700mb. Using brasero getting an error. Here is the log file.

```
Checking session consistency (brasero_burn_check_session_consistency brasero-burn.c:1739)
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI burn:// URI found burn:///QUICK.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///QUICK.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/QUICK.TXT;1 at /QUICK.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///RAID.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/RAID.TXT;1 at /RAID.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///ABOUT.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ABOUT.TXT;1 at /ABOUT.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///ISOLINUX.CAT;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ISOLINUX.CAT;1 at /ISOLINUX.CAT;1
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///DBAN.BZI;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/DBAN.BZI;1 at /DBAN.BZI;1
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///ISOLINUX.BIN;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ISOLINUX.BIN;1 at /ISOLINUX.BIN;1
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///WARNING.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/WARNING.TXT;1 at /WARNING.TXT;1
BraseroBurnURI Information retrieval for burn:///ISOLINUX.CFG;1
BraseroBurnURI Added file /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ISOLINUX.CFG;1 at /ISOLINUX.CFG;1
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_add_track
BraseroBurnURI called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroBurnURI Finished track successfully
BraseroBurnURI stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLocalTrack called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLocalTrack no remote URIs
BraseroLocalTrack stopping
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_output_type
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles stopping
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_output_type
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumFiles Adding graft for checksum file /.checksum.md5 file:///tmp/brasero_tmp_2C7Y1W.md5
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_add_track
BraseroChecksumFiles called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumFiles Finished track successfully
BraseroChecksumFiles stopping
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibisofs creating volume
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_data_label
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /DBAN.BZI;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/DBAN.BZI;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /RAID.TXT;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/RAID.TXT;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /ABOUT.TXT;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ABOUT.TXT;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /QUICK.TXT;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/QUICK.TXT;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /.checksum.md5, URI = file:///tmp/brasero_tmp_2C7Y1W.md5
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /WARNING.TXT;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/WARNING.TXT;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /ISOLINUX.CFG;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ISOLINUX.CFG;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /ISOLINUX.BIN;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ISOLINUX.BIN;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs Adding graft disc path = /ISOLINUX.CAT;1, URI = /home/lvl1/Downloads/dban-2.2.7_i586/ISOLINUX.CAT;1
BraseroLibisofs Found parent
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs Finished track successfully
BraseroLibisofs stopping
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibisofs output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_UI9V1W.bin toc = none
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs Entering thread
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_image_output
BraseroLibisofs writing to file /tmp/brasero_tmp_UI9V1W.bin
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibisofs Getting out thread
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_image_output
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_add_track
BraseroLibisofs called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibisofs Finished track successfully
BraseroLibisofs stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_output_size_for_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage output set (IMAGE) image = /tmp/brasero_tmp_IT4S1W.bin toc = none
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_input_type
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Starting checksuming file /tmp/brasero_tmp_UI9V1W.bin (size = 10788864)
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_fd_out
BraseroChecksumImage called brasero_job_get_current_track
BraseroChecksumImage Setting new checksum (type = 2) 1c2fe9252093b95b8a2f21b520b42aa9 ((null) before)
BraseroChecksumImage Finished track successfully
BraseroChecksumImage stopping
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn unsupported operation
BraseroLibburn deactivating
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_device
BraseroLibburn Drive (/dev/sr0) init result = 1
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_flags
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_media
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_fd_in
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_tracks
BraseroLibburn Setting multi 0
BraseroLibburn Setting burnproof 0
BraseroLibburn Setting dummy 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_convert_fs_adr( /dev/sr0 )
BraseroLibburn Writing
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_dangerous
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn burn_drive_is_enumerable_adr( /dev/sr0 ) is true
BraseroLibburn Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
BraseroLibburn Allocating buffer via mmap()
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn cd Profile= 09h , obs= 32768 , obs_pad= 0
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn TAO pre-track 01 : get_nwa(0)=1, d=0 , demand=10788864 , cap=736958464

BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [3 0C 00] Write error
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_get_session_output_size
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_set_current_action
BraseroLibburn Libburn reported an error SCSI error on write(2464,16): [3 0C 00] Write error
BraseroLibburn called brasero_job_error
BraseroLibburn finished with an error
BraseroLibburn asked to stop because of an error
    error       = 1
    message = "SCSI error on write(2464,16): [3 0C 00] Write error"
BraseroLibburn stopping
Session error : SCSI error on write(2464,16): [3 0C 00] Write error (brasero_burn_record brasero-burn.c:2856)
```

please help!!!

Comment: There are some possible causes: 1) damaged disk 2) damaged drive 3) damaged image. Looking at your log, I say is either the drive or the disk that is damaged.

Comment: please edit your question so that the error report is in code format. It makes reading your question remarkably easier. Welcome to ask ubuntu!

Comment: you can easily do this by adding 4 spaces before each line of text :)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing K3b and using that instead of Brasero.

Answer (score 0):

> BraseroLibburn SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): [3 0C 00] Write error

This error was reported by the drive. It indicates that the
physical impact of the laser beam on the medium dye did not
yield a usable result.

The burn program (in this case my libburn) is not to blame
for this kind of error. It is a thing between drive and medium.

Given the price of CD-R media, i would propose you try a
different pack of them, best from a different sales brand.
(Regrettably one can hardly guess the real manufacturer from
 the brand name printed on the sales box.)

If you already have another burner, then try the unwilling
brand of CD-R in that one.

Have a nice day :)

Thomas